# Clean url in my existing web site

Tags: .htaccess

I have too many doubts about this topic.

I want to create a clean url website. I know it's possible using .htaccess. Is .htaccsess support in all servers? Where did I get the server information? Using Php info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.htaccess** files are used in web servers such as **Apache**. Many other web servers like Sun Java System Web Server and Zeus Web Server implement the same synthax. But if you're using PHP, you are probably using Apache.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)

You can get info about the web server by using the **phpinfo()** function in PHP.

Comment: yes. I got a page containing site  specification. From  there which is the server name? Is _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]? it is Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 in my web site ..

Comment: Apache/2.2.14 is the server and FrontPage is a Microsoft software for web developpers. It seems you have Apache so you can use .htaccess